# How do I concatenate two columns separated by '/' only if both columns are not null?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, concatenation, notnull

I'm trying to concatenate two columns, with the values separated by '/' only if both columns are not null.
If either column is null then '/' should not be printed.
Example:

current output :

```
concat(concat(purpose,'/'),priority) 
     abc/xyz
     /xyz
     abc/
```

Expected Output :

```
     abc/xyz
     xyz
     abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` (see line #9):

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 'abc', 'xyz' from dual union all
  3     select null , 'xyz' from dual union all
  4     select 'abc', null  from dual
  5    )
  6  select col1,
  7         col2,
  8         --
  9         col1 || case when col1 is not null and col2 is not null then '/' end || col2 result
 10  from test;

COL1  COL2  RESULT
----- ----- -------
abc   xyz   abc/xyz
      xyz   xyz
abc         abc

SQL>
```

---

Or, use a *trick* - remove leading/trailing (read: *both*) slashes:

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 'abc', 'xyz' from dual union all
  3     select null , 'xyz' from dual union all
  4     select 'abc', null  from dual
  5    )
  6  select col1,
  7         col2,
  8         trim(both '/' from col1 ||'/'|| col2) result
  9  from test;

COL1  COL2  RESULT
----- ----- -------
abc   xyz   abc/xyz
      xyz   xyz
abc         abc

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we are using `CASE WHEN` to look for the conditions explained in the question. The first condition is checking if both columns are not `Null`. If that is the case then we concat the two columns together with
`/` in between.

If we have a case when one of the column is `Null` then we simply return the value of the column which is not Null. For that purpose we are using `COALESCE`. `COALESCE` always returns the firs non-null value.

```
Select
    col_one,
    col_two,
    case when col_one is not null and col_two is not null 
    then concat(col_one, "/",col_two) 
          else COALESCE(col_one,col_two) end as concat_final
    from table
```

Comment: @Gurudiksha Dhingra does this help ?